# Error Bound of composite trapezium rule

Tags: integration, approximation, approximate-integration

Given the function: $f(x) = \cos(2x) \exp\left(-x^2\right)$

I estimated $\int_{-2}^2 f(x) \ dx$ using the formula. 
I need to calculate the error bound using the formula:
$$
R = −\frac{b−a}{12} \cdot h^2 \cdot \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}(\xi)
$$
Where $(d^2 y/dx^2)(ξ)$ is the maximum of the second derivative. I can tried calculating the function at both limits getting the same answer of, -0.17075...

Is there a way to measure if this answer is correct or do I just hope for the best, I cant see the pattern as to where the function will be a maximum.

Comment: so does that mean the maximum value for the second derivative is 1?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see that the function $f$ is symmetric around zero, i.e. $f(-x) = f(x)$. Sometimes we say such $f$ is even. One other obvious place to check is at zero, and $f(0)=1$, and it's easy to see that is the global maximum, since both the cosine and the exponent cannot exceed one.

Comment: so does that mean the maximum value for the second derivative is 1?

Comment: @MitulSuchak no, for the function itself. You can compute the second derivative analytically and find the maximum

Comment: I mean in the error equation do i sub in 1 for d^2y/dx^2 part?

Comment: @MitulSuchak No, given $f$, compute $f''(x)$ and bound similarly